# ListView with check box call ischecked and else both same time on scrolling

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Hello i have a listview with checkbox, my problem is when i check the checkbox and scroll the list in checkchanged listener "ischecked" and "else" both execute i think while on scrolling when the the checked checkbox disappears it dont maintain  its state
I want when i check the check box (ischecked) should call and when i uncheck the checkbox "else" should call.

Here is my Adapter class

```
public class NamesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<EmployeeModel> employeeModelList;
private Context context;
private EmployeeModel employeeModel;
private ListView listView;
public static String check = "stop";
public String name;
int ii;
int getPosition;
boolean isShowing = false;
public NamesAdapter(List<EmployeeModel> employeeModelList, Context context) {

    this.employeeModelList = employeeModelList;
    this.context = context;


}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return employeeModelList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    // return employeeModelList.get(i);
    return employeeModelList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     ViewHolder viewHolder=null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.empname_listview_model, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox, viewHolder.checkbox);


    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
            // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.

            //employeeModel = employeeModelList.get(position);

            //name = employeeModel.getName();
            getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
            employeeModelList.get(getPosition).setChecked(buttonView.isChecked());

            if (isChecked){
                //getPosition = finalViewHolder.checkbox.getId();
                check="start";
                Toast.makeText(context, "This is if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               displayEmployeeNamesData();

            }
            else {

                check="stop";
                    Toast.makeText(context, "This is else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    });

    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);  // This line is important.
    viewHolder.checkbox.setText(employeeModelList.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(employeeModelList.get(position).isChecked());


    return convertView;
}



public void displayEmployeeNamesData() {
    NewEmployeeDBTable newEmployeeDBTable = new NewEmployeeDBTable(context);

    SQLiteDatabase dataBase = newEmployeeDBTable.getWritableDatabase();
    //the SQL command to fetched all records from the table
    String sql = "SELECT eid FROM "
            + NewEmployeeDBTable.EmployeNameTable + " where ename='" + name + "'";
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ii = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NewEmployeeDBTable.eid));


        }
        while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mCursor.close();
}


private static class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox checkbox;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you see a random change of checkboxes state? Can you describe exactly using the following terminology and information?

1) Click on Row 1 checkbox and check this employee
2) Touch on Row 5 and scroll the listview down
3) Release the finger while Row 5 is still on ListView visible set.

-==RESULTS==-
Row 5 is now checked or unchecked?
Which row changed its state?

Comment: Checkboxes dont changes its positions Lets say if i chck the first checkbox in the list and scroll the list the "else" condition in the list execute because of Layout Inflater i think, and when i scroll up the list again again "ischecked" condition executes.

Comment: I never said that the position of the views is changing but the checkbox's state. It would be really helpful having a reproduce scenario in steps, as this can be caused by to many factors. Does the checkbox's state changes while scrolling AND the specific viewholder gets out of the visible listview area? I cannot help you if you don't answer my questions or provide the Reproduce scenario as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

`OnCheckedChangeListener()` will call when you click on `CheckBox` or when you call `mCheckBox.setCheck(value)` in code.
When you scroll on your `ListView`, the `getView()` method will call to recreate `ListView` row and inside your `getView()` you have call `viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(...)` => `OnCheckedChangeListener` call

To solve it you can use `setOnClickListener` like

```
final EmployeeModel employee = employeeModelList.get(getPosition);
holder.mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        employee.setChecked(!employee.isChecked());
    }
});
viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(employee.isChecked());
```

because `OnClickListener()` won't call when you call `viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(...)`

Comment: I tried to use onClick Listener but the problem is when i scroll the list the check box unchecked or checked other boxes automatically

Comment: @ArslanShahid maybe it is another problem. you can check my simple demo here https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/StackOverFlowDemo/tree/master/CheckBoxInRecyclerView. use `setOnClickListener` work well